# Why does exclamation mark within double quotes cause a Bash error?

Tags: bash

Please look at these commands:

```
$ notify-send SYNC TIME!
$ notify-send 'SYNC TIME!'
$ notify-send "SYNC TIME!"
bash: !": event not found
$
```

The first two commands produce a notification bubble as expected. The third gives the error shown.

and

```
$ echo SYNC TIME!
SYNC TIME!
$ echo 'SYNC TIME!'
SYNC TIME!
$ echo "SYNC TIME!"
bash: !": event not found
$
```

Here as well, the `echo` works for first two commands but not in the third.

More problems here (although I was not planning on using this): both `notify-send "SYNC!TIME"` and `echo "SYNC!TIME"` give `bash: !TIME": event not found`.

But both `notify-send` and `echo` work with `"SYNC! TIME"`

Can someone please explain why the `bash: !": event not found` error appears?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`!` is the default history expansion character in Bash, see the section "HISTORY EXPANSION" in the [Bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html)

- History expansion doesn't take place if the `!` is enclosed by single quotes, as in

  ```
  notify-send 'SYNC TIME!'
  ```
- History expansion doesn't take place if the `!` is followed by a space, tab, newline, carriage return,  or `=`, as in

  ```
  notify-send SYNC TIME!
  ```
- History expansion *does* take place in

  ```
  echo "SYNC TIME!"
  ```

  So you'll get an error if there isn't a command starting with `"` in your history

Comment: This misbehavior can be fixed by adding to your `.bashrc` the line `set +H`. Note that `!` is already non-special in scripting; treating it as special would break many standards-conforming scripts. It's only treated as "special" in interactive shells, and only by default until you fix it. :-)

Answer (score 15):

Because in bash, `!` is a reserved word (OK, character), it has special meaning in different contexts. In this particular case, you are falling afoul of its significance in history searching. From `man bash`:

```
   History expansions introduce words from the history list into the input
   stream, making it easy to repeat commands, insert the  arguments  to  a
   previous command into the current input line, or fix errors in previous
   commands quickly.

  [...]

   History expansions are introduced by
   the appearance of the  history  expansion  character,  which  is  !  by
   default.   Only  backslash  (\) and single quotes can quote the history
   expansion character.
```

Basically, what this means is that bash will take the characters after the `!` and search your history for the first command it finds that starts with those characters. It is easier to demonstrate than explain:

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ !e
echo foo
foo
```

The `!` activated history expansion, which matched the first command starting with `e` which was the previously run `echo foo` which was then run again. So, when you wrote `"SYNC TIME!"`, bash saw the `!"`, searched history for a command starting with `"`, failed and complained about it. You can get the same error by running, for example `!nocommandstartswiththis`.

To print an exclamation mark, you need to escape it in one of these two ways:

```
echo 'Hello world!'
echo Hello world\!
```

Comment: `echo Hello world!` does work --- history expansion is not triggered by blanks ;-) (ah, the nice corner cases...)

Comment: It's better to rely on escaping the exclamation mark than blanks, though.

Comment: @Rmano I prefer to explicitly say so rather than guide me of a behavior that it's possible to change

Comment: `!` is a [reserved word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Reserved-Word-Index) in `bash`, as [POSIX also declares](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04). But I'm pretty sure its status as one is **completely unrelated** to its role in history expansion and irrelevant to its treatment in double quotes. `!` is a reserved word because it negates a command/pipeline's exit status, so it can't be used as a command. No other reserved word is special in a `"`-quoted context, while `$` is *not* a reserved word but *is* treated specially.