# Terminal replacing ! followed by a number with a command

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

I'm very confused about my ubuntu terminal session, it seems to replace sections in commands that start by `!` followed by a number with seemingly random commands. It does that with `!87` replacing it with `screen -l` and also with `!88` and replaced it with `ls`.

Any ideas why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why does exclamation mark within double quotes cause a Bash error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434832/why-does-exclamation-mark-within-double-quotes-cause-a-bash-error)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's `bash`'s history expansion, e.g.

```
!87
```

re-executes the command from history line `87`.

You find the description of this feature in [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc28), section “HISTORY EXPANSION”:

```
       An  event  designator  is  a  reference  to a command line entry in the
       history list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative to
       the current position in the history list.

       !      Start  a  history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
              newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option
              is enabled using the shopt builtin).
       !n     Refer to command line n.
       !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
```

So to quickly call the last command, do `!-1` and for the fifth last command `!-5`. A handy synonym for `!-1` is `!!` – if you called e.g. `apt install something` and forgot the `sudo`, just execute `sudo !!` and you're good.

> Only backslash (**\**) and single quotes can  quote  the  history expansion character.

To avoid history expansion, you need to either escape the exclamation mark with a backslash (`\!`) or use single quotes (`'!'`).

Comment: to pass a litereal `!` to your commands and avoid history expansion, you'll need to single-quote or escape them:  `foo '!87'` or `foo \!87`.  (double-quotes will also perform the expansion on their contents.)